# Installing Extensions in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using Selenuim Webdriver to load .CRX extension file in chrome browser in C#.
Is there any way to install the .CRX extension permanently in chrome browser ?
I already done the developer mode check, updated url in manifest.json but no success.
Is their any other driver which install extensions permanently in chrome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you visited [this](https://superuser.com/questions/626081/chrome-extension-adding-permanently) post from the superuser? If not, you can try the steps/process in the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/626847) provided.

Comment: what does it mean by `permanently in chrome browser` ? once you upload ext. in chrome , it lasts until you remove it from the browser.

Answer (score -1):

go to chrome://extensions and the open the file app on your computer, drag the .crx file onto the chrome://extensions page and then drop it there, it should say something like "drop to install"